# How to edit Virtual Device? Android Studio - Java

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't find a button to click on to edit my Virtual Devices on Android Studio 4.1.1. AVD Manager. Is this option got disabled and I need to create a new virtual device every time that I want to change configuration?

Comment: Update your question with the picture where you are looking to edit the device and cannot find option to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st click the icon of Avd Manager from Android Studio like that
[image]

2nd click on the pen icon like that
[image]

3rd here you are.
[image]